# Python loop: calculate sum between 2 random values from 1-10

Tags: python

I have to generate two random integers between 1-10 then calculate the sum of the numbers in the range. Could anyone help me how to put that in a loop?

```
import random
sum= 0

from random import randrange
num1 = (randrange(1,11))
num2 = (randrange(1,11))
count = sum
sumtotal = sum(range(num1 + 1, num2))
while count <= 10
print ("The sum is", sumtotal)
```

Comment: sum is the name of a built-in python function. How are you going to define your variable ```count``` as ```sum```? Also, do you want to iterate 10 times, or do you want to repeat the calculation as many times as needed until your result is <= 10?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```py
import random as r

r.seed(4)

def randsumware():

    num1 = r.randint(1,11)
    num2 = r.randint(1,11)

    return num1+num2

res = randsumware()
print ("The sum is: {}".format(res))

while randsumware() <= 10:
    res = randsumware()
    print ("The sum is: {}".format(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of list comprehension, that generates a list of 2 random integers. `sum()` adds up all items in the list:

```
import random
result = sum([random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(2)])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: you do not need to explicitly iterate over all elements in the range `[i, j]`. Using the sum of arithmetic progression, you can evaluate the sum in constant time:

`(1+2+...+j)-(1+2+...+i-1) = (1-1)+(2-2)+...+(i-1-i+1)+i+(i+1)+...+j = i+(i+1)+...+(j-1)+j`

```py
import random


def arithmetic_progression_sum(n):
    return ((1 + n) * n) // 2


def subsequence_sum(a:int, b:int):
    assert(a <= b)    
    return arithmetic_progression_sum(b) - arithmetic_progression_sum(a-1)


def run():
    a = random.randint(1, 10)
    b = random.randint(a, 10)

    return subsequence_sum(a, b)
```